# How does mount know that it's a cifs mount without -t?

Tags: mount, cifs

So this command: `/bin/mount -o soft,cache=none,rw,nosuid,noexec,pass="" //$ServerIP/share $LocalDir` works, but I thought it'd need `-t cifs` added.

I see the man page says

> If no -t option is given, or if the auto type is specified, mount will try to guess the desired type. Mount uses the blkid or volume_id library for guessing the filesystem type; if that does not turn up anything that looks familiar, mount will try to read the file /etc/filesystems, or, if that does not exist, /proc/filesystems. All of the filesystem types listed there will be tried, except for those that are labeled "nodev" (e.g., devpts, proc and nfs). If /etc/filesystems ends in a line with a single * only, mount will read /proc/filesystems afterwards.

But my `/etc/filesystems` doesn't have `cifs` and my `/proc/filesystems` has `nodev cifs`. So how does  `blkid` or `volume_id` work in my case? Does `mount` assume cifs once it sees the double slashes(`//`) or is there some other method? Is there documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does `mount` assume cifs once it sees the double slashes(`//`) or is there some other method?

Yes, that's exactly how (lib)mount does it -- if source is not a block device it assumes it is a network location -- if it has `:` it's NFS and with `//` it's assumed to be CIFS. You can check the [mnt_context_guess_srcpath_fstype](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libmount/src/context.c#L1989) libmount function which is used when `auto` (or nothing) is specified as type.

Comment: Note that specifically POSIX specifies that paths that begin with exactly two slashes have an implementation-defined meaning. So, the idea that this path identifies a network share and not a file is fully supported by the standard.